# Installing Windows 10 IoT Core on simulated devices (possibly Azure Hub)

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, azure-iot-hub, windows-10-iot-core

> Notice: This might sound like a not-so-thought-through question to
>   some people.

Hello,

I need to make a simple demo application running on Windows 10 IoT Core and test it properly for educational purposes. The problem is that I have no available Raspberry Pi devices (or anything embedded). Apparently, it is possible to set-up a simulated Raspberry Pi device running on Azure Hub - like explained [in Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-web-simulator-get-started).

Is it possible to install Windows 10 IoT on such a simulated device? If not, what are the other approaches to simulating Raspberry devices and running Windows IoT on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the Windows 10 IoT Core on the VMware workstation:

[image]

More details can be found in the [How to run Windows 10 IoT Core in VMware Workstation](http://autosqa.com/2016/04/14/how-to-run-windows-10-iot-core-in-vmware-workstation/)

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I will be posting my results here once I get to try it.

Comment: Turned out to be troublesome virtualizing Windows IoT on VMware. Mostly because of the default SCSI hard drive controller configuration.

I ended up using VirtualBox with MBM x64-bit build.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. It is not running an OS of any kind, it just makes it look like you have node running on a Pi. You need to look at something like qemu. I've run Raspbian in qemu. Never tried Windows IoT core.

https://www.qemu.org/